# Sour cream pound cake

Tags: baking

I have a recipe that calls for

- a Duncan Hines butter cake mix
- 4 eggs
- ½ cup sugar
- 1 cup Wesson oil
- 8 ozs sour cream.

Cook in preheated oven 1½ hours at 300.

I have made numerous cakes like this and they turned out beautiful until Duncan Hines changed the cake mix from 18oz to 15oz. Since then I have not been able to make this cake without problems.

- I added ⅓ cup of another mix and it ran over and fell.
- I made a mixture of 1½ cups flour, 1 cup sugar, 2 teaspoons baking powder, ¼ teaspoon baking soda and added 6 tablespoons of this mixture to my cake mix and it still ran over and fell. This one tasted fine but was not pretty.

Do you have any idea what I can do to make it where it won’t fall and run over?

Comment: If Duncan Hines made their box smaller by 16.6%, have you tried decreasing your other ingredients by a similar amount, rather than adding more things?

Comment: I have not decreased the other ingredients, really don’t know where to start to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If the package of cake mix got smaller (and otherwise didn't change) then you could try reducing every ingredient by a similar amount, to keep all the ratios the same.

If the package decreased from 18 to 15 ounces, that's makes the new package 83.3% (15÷18) the size of the old one. You'll want to reduce other ingredients similarly.

Your "18 oz recipe" was:

- 18 oz cake mix
- 4 eggs
- ½ cup sugar
- 1 cup oil
- 8 oz sour cream

With the eggs, an exact reduction would be 3⅓ eggs, and ⅓ egg is just silly. I'd suggest rounding down to 3. To keep the other measurements at round fractions, the ratios will get thrown off a bit.

If you keep all the measurements even fractions for a "15 oz recipe" you might try:

- 15 oz cake mix
- 3 eggs
- ⅓ cup sugar
- ¾ cup oil
- 6 oz sour cream

I've rounded everything down on that... Which means I think it might be a touch dry compared to the original.

A slightly fussier attempt at a "15 oz recipe" would be something like this:

- 15 oz cake mix
- 3 eggs
- ⅓ cup + 1 Tablespoon sugar
- ¾ cup + 1 Tablespoon oil
- 7 oz sour cream

That still might need some tweaking to get it "just right"... And of course, if Duncan Hines changed more than just the size of the box, your recipe might need more careful adjustment.

Comment: Baking time will also likely be shorter for a smaller quantity of batter.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix online last year, 2022.  It calls for adding 1 cup of self rising flour to same recipe.   Works!  But tastes different.   This year I'm following a bundt cake recipe that adds 1 box instant pudding.  Also adding 4 TB self rising flour.  So far, so good.   I believe they changed more than just the size.  Taste is not as rich.